# Nginx reverse proxy - Nonexistent subdirectories and subdomains redirecting?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have the following nginx config:

```
upstream toshiba15 {
    server toshiba15.local:80;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name my.domain.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/startssl-nginx.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/startssl-nginx.key;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/;

    location /dev/ {
            proxy_pass http://toshiba15/;
            proxy_redirect http://toshiba15/ /dev/;
            proxy_set_header        Host    $host;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

Mostly works as intended, but one problem- when I specify a nonexistent sub-directory in the uri, it displays the content at the root of the proxied (toshiba15) server!

The proxied server has a stock nginx config- no changes.

**EDIT**: I resolved the subdomain problem by adding another server that returns 404, and using regexes for my server_names

Additionally, if I specify an undefined subdomain, it redirects to the root of the proxy server (my.domain.com)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured out what to do. On the upstream server I moved the root and index directives inside the location block and removed the tries.

On the proxy, to take care of the subdomain problem I set up a catch-all at the top without a servername and returned 404. I added a regex to the main domain name.